# How to get a timeout callback on a signalr hub client?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'd like to handle timeout callback on a hub call to garantee that server received my "message", how can I do that?

I looked at signalR wiki, googled about it but found nothing!

That was the way I thought the interface would be:

```
  var hubcon = new HubConnection("myurl", useDefaultUrl: false);
   IHubProxy chatHub = hubcon.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
   chatHub.On("timeout", data =>
                {
                    //do something
                });

   hubcon.Start().Wait(1000);

   chatHub.Invoke("EnviarMensagem", new { nome = nome, mensagem = mensagem }).Wait();

   hubcon.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `Wait` anyway, you can set a timeout and look at the return value to see if the server finished processing your invocation:

```
   if (!chatHub.Invoke("EnviarMensagem", ...).Wait(10000))
   {
       // The server did not respond to the invocation within 10 seconds
   }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644.aspx